# Foreach-object returning 'cannot index into a null array', but works fine when I copy each line of the loop

Tags: arrays, powershell, hashtable, foreach-object

I have a script that I've been conceptualizing and it sort of became centered around this idea of throwing lining up arrays into hash tables, and then call on them with a foreach-object $_ index in order to run through a command or output, with the least amount of redundant code written.

I have tried this idea so many different times, it just doesn't seem to work. Not sure if I'm just being rather dumb, or if there's something else I'm missing here.

I'm able to get other hash tables and arrays to work with this method, but this one is giving me problems.

i'll break it down.

```
The first array will be the first line
The second array will be the 2nd line...
so on and so forth until the 6th.
```

each line has several values, but each of those values that correspond to the same item as the one above and below it... think of an excel spreadsheet... sort of like that.

at the end of this array/hashtable, I try to collect each one into...

```
$control = ( 0..5 | % { first[$_] ; second[$_] ; third[$_] ; fourth[$_] ; fifth[$_] ; sixth[$_] } )
```

I've tried every permutation I can think of, with an at sign, without one, throwing control into the curlies, using parenthesis instead of curlies, using commas, this just doesn't seem to want to work. I have also tried placing an empty control=() before doing the loop by itself, nothing seems to work... I can't seem to get away from this error "index outside the bounds of the array"

...and just when I think I've gotten it to work, I call on the variable and it's empty. Nada.

So for now, this seems to work, but it sucks...

```
$Control = @{ 0 = ( $first[0] , $second[0] , $third[0] , $fourth[0] , $fifth[0] );
              1 = ( $first[1] , $second[1] , $third[1] , $fourth[1] , $fifth[1] );
              2 = ( $first[2] , $second[2] , $third[2] , $fourth[2] , $fifth[2] );
              3 = ( $first[3] , $second[3] , $third[3] , $fourth[3] , $fifth[3] );
              4 = ( $first[4] , $second[4] , $third[4] , $fourth[4] , $fifth[4] );
              5 = ( $first[5] , $second[5] , $third[5] , $fourth[5] , $fifth[5] );
              6 = ( $first[6] , $second[6] , $third[6] , $fourth[6] , $fifth[6] )}
```

I'm looking to do this with the least amount of code, i'm just not sure why this one doesn't work.

By the way, if I call on $control[0] or what have you after the fact, the desired end result is to print those variables to the screen ........

Index was outside the bounds of the array. x5 thousand times...

Comment: i see that you have found a workaround ... but the _design_ seems wrong in the 1st place. [*grin*] have you tried building an object for each row, storing that in an array of of such objects, and THEN displaying the rows? heck, you can use `ConvertTo-CSV` to make a csv layout if you need that. ///// i suspect that i am not understanding something ... [*blush*]

Comment: https://github.com/secure-digits-plus-llc/Hybrid-DesiredStateController/blob/master/Initialize-HybridServer.ps1

Look for the DISM lines.

Comment: Basically what you said is what I did, I was just trying to use less commands and more variable movement and looping. It was chaotic before, it probably still is and i'll get around to cleaning it up a bit more, but it's doing what I had hoped. this project was a serious pain in the neck for sure

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

```
$control=@( 0..5 )

0..5 | % { $control[$_]=@($first[$_];$second[$_];$third[$_];$fourth[$_];$fifth[$_])}
```

can't believe it took me that long to realize I had to put the array into the empty field above... im glad i solved it but feel silly for not trying that sooner.